# Please help with my Natural Deduction question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have trouble solving this past exam question

[Natrual Deduction question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTN6w.jpg)

I am only allowed to use the $18$ rules as attached - $8$ rules of inference AND $10$ rules of replacement PLUS conditional proof and Indirect proof.

I tried using the indirect proof, which negates the $L$ to become $\sim L$, then I get $\sim(P\to R)$ and $\sim(R\to M)$ but then I am stuck

Please help with this question! Thank you!

[RULES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3sV.jpg)

Comment: You need only 1 and 3 with Ecluded Middle: $R \lor \lnot R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Once you have ~$(P \rightarrow R)$ and ~$(R \rightarrow M)$ use Implication to rewrite the conditionals as disjunctions, and then apply DeMorgan